# preg_match rule to detect all bots except google,yahoo,bing

Tags: php

I found this in my AW stats:

Unknown robot (identified by 'bot' followed by a space or one of the following characters _+:,.;/-)

636,127+83 17.95 GB

This is what is consuming maximum bandwidth on my website. 4 times than what google bot is consuming.

I don't know what these bots are, or what amount of traffic they are sending, but total hits by bots on my site this month has crossed 1M, which resulted in a "bandwidth exceeded" error message

Is there a way to block all these using php preg?

But I don't want to block google bot, yahoo bot and bing bot.

Can someone please give me the preg_match rule in PHP to detect these bots?

I want to use PHP so that I can log their entries before sending a 403 code.

Thanks

Comment: *Can someone please give me the preg_match rule* > What have you tried first by yourself?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but the max I was able to do was this: preg_match( '/bot/', $user_agent_string ) but that detects all bots and doesn't exclude google,yahoo, and bing

Comment: What about simply using `piwik device detector` ? https://github.com/piwik/device-detector buy I prefer to hide my server behind `CloudFlare` service. It has anti-crawler/firewall/ddos and many more features.

Answer (score 0):

In fact detecting headers is not good idea.

Today You catch bot with weird name, tomorrow it become `Google bot` and do the same unusual operations.

I'm using [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) and it saves my web app/system from hot-linking, attacks, crawlers, bad guys and etc., caches static content, saves server's bandwidth and many more.